# Java-WS unmarshal error: Unexpected element "xyz. Expected elements are ""

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, java-ws

I've got a Java Web services client talking to a remote .Net SOAP web service.  I need to substitute raw XML for one of the arguments, instead of packing and unpacking the corresponding JAXB Java object.

PROBLEM:

1. I chose to use "javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller" to insert the raw XML. (I don't know if there's another, better way).
2. I verified the call works if I use JAXB, and recorded the SOAP request message (see below).
3. I get `WS error: Unexpected element "requestOptions". Expected elements are "".` when I try to add the XML directly.

WORKING JAVA CLIENT (returns a valid "RequestOptions" JAXB object):

```
private RequestOptions mkRequestOptions () throws Exception {
  RequestOptions requestOptions = new com.mypackage.shwsclients.ObjectFactory().createRequestOptions ();
  requestOptions.setTransactionId("007");
  requestOptions.setUserName("testName");
  requestOptions.setWorkflowName("testWorkflow");
  requestOptions.setModuleName("testModule");
  return requestOptions;
}
```

FAILING JAVA CLIENT (fails trying to unmarshal an XML string):

```
private static String theXml = 
  "<requestOptions>\n" +
  "  <WorkflowName>unmarshalTestWorkflow</WorkflowName>\n" +
  "  <ModuleName>unmarshalTestModule</ModuleName>\n" +
  "  <UserName>unmarshalTestName</UserName>\n" +
  "  <TransactionId>0099</TransactionId>\n" +
  "</requestOptions>\n";

private RequestOptions mkRequestOptions () throws Exception {
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RequestOptions.class);
  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
  Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader (theXml));  // DIES HERE!!!!
  RequestOptions requestOptions = (RequestOptions)obj;
  return requestOptions;
}
```

SUCCESSFUL SOAP REQUEST:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <GetAddressData xmlns="http://myservice.com/wsdl/myservice">
      <requestOptions>
        <WorkflowName>testWorkflow</WorkflowName>
        <ModuleName>testModule</ModuleName>
        <UserName>testName</UserName>
        <TransactionId>007</TransactionId>
      </requestOptions>
      <zipCode>90210</zipCode>
    </GetAddressData>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

AUTO-GENERATED PROXY CODE:

```
//
// Generated By:JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01 (JAXB RI IBM 2.2.4)
//
package com.mypackage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
...

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "RequestOptions", propOrder = {
    "workflowName",
    "moduleName",
    "userName",
    "transactionId"
})
public class RequestOptions
    implements Serializable
{

    @XmlElement(name = "WorkflowName")
    protected String workflowName;
    @XmlElement(name = "ModuleName")
    protected String moduleName;
    @XmlElement(name = "UserName")
    protected String userName;
    @XmlElement(name = "TransactionId")
    protected String transactionId;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.

The solution was to put all the arguments into XML, then unmarshal the entire message.

I thought I would be able to unmarshal a single argument. Instead, I needed to unmarshal the entire message - the class JAXB annotated "@XmlRootElement".